# Reversing Display Order of Mixed Arabic and English Titles using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have noticed an issue with the display order of article titles that contain both Arabic and English words when they appear in Google search results. Currently, the trend shows English words first, followed by Arabic ones.

As an example, consider the following title:

Original Title:

**شرح أداة DigiSpark OverMaster منافس Rubber Ducky**

I aim to have the title displayed in the correct order, like this:

Desired Display:

**Rubber Ducky منافس DigiSpark OverMaster شرح أداة**

I'm seeking a PHP code solution to address this problem and ensure that the titles are consistently displayed in the correct direction. Please note that I want to handle this programmatically through PHP rather than relying on CSS RTL (Right-to-Left) styles.

Iwant  to display like that :

[image]

I have tried doing this through many functions. I think it is very slow, and this is not what I want because it reflects the English letters incorrectly.

This is an example of what I have achieved and I do not want anything like it :

```html
function reverseTitle($title) {
  $words = explode(' ', $title);
  $reversedWords = array_reverse($words);
  $reversedTitle = implode(' ', $reversedWords);
  return $reversedTitle;
}

function getLastArabicWords($inputString) {
  $arabicRegex = '/[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\s]+$/u';
  preg_match($arabicRegex, $inputString, $match);
  return $match ? trim($match[0]) : null;
}


function containsMultipleEnglishWords($arabicWord) {
  $englishWordPattern = '/\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/';
  $matches = [];
  preg_match_all($englishWordPattern, $arabicWord, $matches);
  return count($matches[0]) > 1;
}


function detectEnglishWords($arabicString)
{
    preg_match_all('/\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/u', $arabicString, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}


function mix_title_dir($title) {
try {

$scan_tile           = containsMultipleEnglishWords($title);
$outputTitle         = reverseTitle($title);
$firstArabicWords    = getLastArabicWords($outputTitle);
$reverse_first_words = reverseTitle($firstArabicWords);

if( $scan_tile ){

$theMixTitle = str_replace($firstArabicWords,$reverse_first_words , $outputTitle);

return $theMixTitle;
}else{

  $englishWords = implode(', ', detectEnglishWords($title));

  $wordsToReplace = array(
    $englishWords => "",
    $reverse_first_words => "",
);
$solid_title =  str_replace(array_keys($wordsToReplace), array_values($wordsToReplace), $title) ." ". $englishWords . " ". $reverse_first_words;
return trim($solid_title)  ;
}

} catch (Exception $e) {
  return $title;
}

}

$text = "شرح أداة DigiSpark OverMaster";
echo mix_title_dir($title);
```

## Output :

**Ducky Rubber منافس OverMaster DigiSpark شرح أداة**

Kinda good
But the English word appears
**OverMaster DigiSpark**
not
**DigiSpark OverMaster**